# Capifony and git bare repo

Tags: git, symfony, capifony

I have this deploy.rb file:

```
set :application, "UDA"
set :domain,      "10.0.0.59"
set :deploy_to,   "/home/gitek/www/uda/"
set :app_path,    "app"

set :user,        "gitek"

ssh_options[:port] = 22
set :php_bin, "/usr/bin/php"

set :scm,         :git
#set  :git_enable_submodules,  1
set  :repository,             "#{domain}:/var/repos/uda.git"
set  :deploy_via,             :remote_cache

# Or: `accurev`, `bzr`, `cvs`, `darcs`, `subversion`, `mercurial`, `perforce`, `subversion` or `none`

set :model_manager, "doctrine"
# Or: `propel`
role :web,        domain                         # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app,        domain                         # This may be the same as your `Web` server
role :db,         domain, :primary => true       # This is where Rails migrations will run

set  :keep_releases,  5
set :use_sudo,    false

set :update_vendors, true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true


set :shared_files,      ["app/config/parameters.ini"]
set :shared_children,     [app_path + "/logs", web_path + "/uploads", "vendor"]
```

My repo, is bare repo and it is located in the same server, in "/var/repos/".

The fact is that I´m getting this error when I executed "cap deploy" command:

```
gitek@/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/uda$ cap deploy
  * executing `deploy'
  * executing `deploy:update'
 ** transaction: start
  * executing `deploy:update_code'
    updating the cached checkout on all servers
    executing locally: "git ls-remote 10.0.0.59:/var/repos/uda.git HEAD"
    command finished in 5487ms
  * executing "if [ -d /home/gitek/www/uda/shared/cached-copy ]; then cd /home/gitek/www/uda/shared/cached-copy && git fetch -q origin && git fetch --tags -q origin && git reset -q --hard 051be2de2155dfac7cfb45df0b4c2fb6ca633555 && git clean -q -d -x -f; else git clone -q 10.0.0.59:/var/repos/uda.git /home/gitek/www/uda/shared/cached-copy && cd /home/gitek/www/uda/shared/cached-copy && git checkout -q -b deploy 051be2de2155dfac7cfb45df0b4c2fb6ca633555; fi"
    servers: ["10.0.0.59"]
    [10.0.0.59] executing command
 ** [10.0.0.59 :: err] Permission denied, please try again.
 ** [10.0.0.59 :: err] Permission denied, please try again.
 ** [10.0.0.59 :: err] Permission denied (publickey,password).
 ** [10.0.0.59 :: err] fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
    command finished in 754ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /home/gitek/www/uda/releases/20111013112554; true"
    servers: ["10.0.0.59"]
    [10.0.0.59] executing command
    command finished in 20ms
failed: "sh -c 'if [ -d /home/gitek/www/uda/shared/cached-copy ]; then cd /home/gitek/www/uda/shared/cached-copy && git fetch -q origin && git fetch --tags -q origin && git reset -q --hard 051be2de2155dfac7cfb45df0b4c2fb6ca633555 && git clean -q -d -x -f; else git clone -q 10.0.0.59:/var/repos/uda.git /home/gitek/www/uda/shared/cached-copy && cd /home/gitek/www/uda/shared/cached-copy && git checkout -q -b deploy 051be2de2155dfac7cfb45df0b4c2fb6ca633555; fi'" on 10.0.0.59
gitek@/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/uda$
```

I think that the problem comes because my git repo is a bare one...

does anyone know how to resolve that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your deploy.rb and set the repository like that:

> set  :repository,  "ssh://USER@SERVERIP/var/repos/uda.git"

Don´t forget to add to autorized_keys2 (on your server 10.0.0.59? )

> cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh USER@SERVER "cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys2"

Hope it helps. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to access the server using the network and git can't authenticate due to a missing SSH key.

If the server is on the same deploy machine, it doesn't make sense to clone using a remote connection. Clone the local repository by passing the repository path.

```
set  :repository,  "/var/repos/uda.git"
```

Comment: it doesn't work, it says: "fatal: '/var/repos/uda.git' does not appear to be a git repository"

Comment: Are you sure the path is valid? `cd` to `/var/repos/uda.git` and execute `git status` to make sure it's a valid repository.

Comment: ups! I get this error: "gitek@ubuntu:/var/repos/uda.git$ git status
fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree"

Comment: It's a valid repository. I forgot `git status` doesn't work in base repositories. I'm sorry, I don't know why the clone failed. I should inspect the full log.

Comment: and where can I get the full log?